# How do I sort case-insensitively with jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

It appears that jqGrid is sorting based on case. For example:

`0, 1, 2, A, B, C, Z, a, b, c, z`

Is there a way to sort without case sensitivity?

`0, 1, 2, A, a, B, b, C, c, Z, z`

Answer (score 1):

Use ignoreCase property in your jqGrid.

Documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/96/

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 100,
    rowNum: 10,
    ignoreCase: true,
```

In the above fiddler, try setting the ignoreCase = false and sort the 'Client' column. And, then change it back to true and sort again to see the difference.